# flash in jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, flash

I am using openflashchart in my website that generates multiple flash graphs for a certain model.

I am trying to figure out best way to present these multiple flashes in one page. I have tried slideshow plugins (the issue with them is that the next/previous type elements which are generally over the sliding content, stop working when the content is flash) and I am also trying jquery accordion where each accordion is a flash inside a div. It works well, but during a change there is this jarry transition, I am guessing it's because the flash loads fresh json data everytime it is activated. I have no control over the flash file and no skills to change it.

what's the best way to present this kind of multiple flash content, in one page, in a contained element like accordion or some sort of slide show plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPen flash chart actually has a remote_ofc_load method that will load json data on demand via ajax, that feature solves this problem. I just have to download one instance of the original swf file and then present any number of graphs using the remote_ofc_load method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you just retrieve the JSON data immediately on loading the page, and then cache them ont he client? Then you'd reduce the latency of the transition, because you wouldn't need to go retrieve the data, non?